# Neo4j path traversal - path progress dependent on relationship attribute

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, py2neo

I've been just looking into [neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/) in a bit of spare time, using the [py2neo](http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/) bindings for python. I'm interested in the pathfinding aspect of neo4j. For the purposes of learning I've been creating a simple game-map graph (solar systems, and internal coordinate navigation). Simple pathfinding is very straightforward to implement, and the performance of neo4j is really quite impressive even with long paths over complex networks of nodes.

What I'm now keen to look at is attaching attributes to the relationships which can affect navigation. For example, I want to lock a given relationship to only certain users, characters, or people with a key.

I'm not sure how you can add this into the pathfinding, so that it looks for paths, but as it does so, it checks if there are additional constraints which are met/denied.

Can a path be blocked on the basis of a relationship attribute, i.e. pseudo-representation below:

```
(node 5, 'linked', node 6) with attribute 'path_blocked': True
```

Without pre-conditions:

```
start s=node(22), e=node(46)
MATCH p = shortestPath((s)-[*..100]-(e))
return p
```

Is there a way to make the pathfinder take into account whether a given relationship has an attribute which should block progress on this path?

Answer (score 3):

In Cypher you can filter paths based on relationship properties using the `WHERE` clause.

If you need more control during a traversal you should take a look at the [Traversal API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html). However I'm not sure if traversal API is accessible from py2neo. If not, you can use traversal API inside an [unmanaged extension](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) and access this one via REST.

Comment: Unfortunately, the traversal API are no longer supported in py2neo.